# Unable to load assets in flutter tests

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, assets

rootBundle works great in application but in tests it throws an exception `ERROR: Unable to load asset: assets/config/prod.json`

configuration.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

class Configuration {

  final Map<String, String> _config = {};

  String get(String key) {
    return _config[key];
  }

  Future<void> load() async {
    _config.clear();
    final configString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/config/prod.json');
    final configJson = jsonDecode(configString) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    _config.addAll(Map.castFrom<String, dynamic, String, String>(configJson));
  }

}
```

configuration_test.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:my_app/data/models/configuration.dart';

void main() {

  setUpAll(() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  });

  test('should load configuration', () async {
    final config = Configuration();
    await config.load();
    expect(config.get('client_id'), 'client_id');
  });

}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
...
dev_dependencies:
  ...
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/config/
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17):

I found out what's wrong with my test.
There is `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding` in `flutter_test` package and I should use it instead of `WidgetsFlutterBinding` from `material` package

configuration_test.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:my_app/data/models/configuration.dart';

void main() {

  setUpAll(() {
    TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  });

  test('should load configuration', () async {
    final config = Configuration();
    await config.load();
    expect(config.get('client_id'), 'client_id');
  });

}
```

Comment: for me this didn't work when making integration tests

Answer (score 2):

If you defining `JSON` file in `puspec.yaml` file you have to write full name of your json file like below

```
assets:
  - assets/data.json
```

In your case, path will be

```
assets:
  - assets/config/prod.json
```

Comment: Still working in app but throws exceptions in tests

Answer (score 2):

In case you are encountering this problem [when building a flutter package](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages), know that by default in `pubspec.yaml`, the `flutter` property is set to `null` (`flutter: null`), and the indentation of the assets is wrong.

So, you first need to set the `flutter` property to nothing, like this:
`flutter:`

Then make sure the assets indentation follows this:

```
[2 whitespaces or 1 tab]assets:

[4 whitespaces or 2 tabs]- assets/image1.png

[4 whitespaces or 2 tabs]- assets/image2.png
```